# When a plugin is registered in joomla observer?

Tags: plugins, joomla, virtuemart

I have done a plugin for a simple debug purpose, print some data ( avoiding the code to be delete on each update ) .

I have build a plugin following official tutorial, but code does not go there ( seen with xdebug )

THe plugin isn't registered among observers, so it's action is not thrown. I image that plugin are registered while the plugin is installed? or I can change code after being installed?

Thanks

```
class plgSystemVmdataprint extends JPlugin
{
function onAfterRender()
{

$data = JRequest::get('post');
            if(!($_REQUEST['option']='com_virtuemart' && $_REQUEST['view']='product' && $_REQUEST['task']='edit') )
            {
                $textFIleSave = JPATH_VM_SITE . DS . 'plugins'. DS . 'vmdataprint' . DS . 'productsaveprint'. DS . 'productsave.txt';
                file_put_contents($textFIleSave, print_r($data, true));
            }

}
}
```

Comment: Even after install, you usually have to go into the plugin manager and enable the plugin. Have you done that?

Comment: If the plugin is enabled, what kind of plugin is it? The event onAfterRender will not be invoked in all plugin types (I think your plugin should be of the `system` type). Also, in order for xdebug to pick it up, you need to rebuild your project

Comment: I have read and done the first time, but after trying many time and many modification I have forgot to activate. Thanks for suggestion :(